# Why isn't there "is" in "They did it, thinking it more glamorous than..."?

Tags: present-participles, be, contraction-vs-full-form

Could you please help me with the grammar of this sentence? It's from an essay in a book on IELTS by Cambridge University Press.

*People turn to buying the new brand from overseas nations, perhaps thinking it more glamorous than the one they are used to. As a result, local companies are likely to maximize their profits as they import foreign products.*

Is *it more glamorous* grammatically correct, and if yes, why isn't it *it is more...*?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

*Thinking it [adjective]* is grammatically correct; it's a shorter way of saying *thinking that it is/was [adjective]* or *thinking it to be [adjective]*.

Comment: //....perhaps thinking it more glamorous than the one they are used to......// The sentence can be improved in other respects, but as for your specific question, it is correct. more glamorous than....is correct.  We do not always have to use ...more than...together.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please refer me to some further reading so that I could design practice questions for my students?